# integer parse int not working

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, parseint

I am trying to make a simple addition using java web services. I have a problem getting the input from the `JTextField` into my `int`s so that the program can carry out the addition. The code I have is below. When the user inputs the first value they should click the first button (`butta`) same with the second, once the second is clicked it should show somewhere the result. The integer parsing doesnt seem to work when I click on the buttons its not taking the value.

```
 public class Wscalcclient {
           static int aa=0, bb=0, cc=0;
        String str = new String(); 
        JTextField fielda, fieldb;
        JTextField fieldc;

        Wscalcclient()
        {  JButton butta, buttb;
           JLabel result;
           JPanel panel;

           JFrame frame  = new JFrame();
           frame.setBackground(Color.white);
           frame.setForeground(Color.black);
           frame.setSize(500,250);

           panel = new JPanel();
           panel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
           panel.setForeground(Color.black);
           panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));

           butta = new JButton("enter number a");
           buttb = new JButton("enter number b");
           result = new JLabel("result a+b=");
           fielda = new JTextField();
           fieldb = new JTextField();
           fieldc = new JTextField();

           panel.add(butta);
           panel.add(fielda);
           panel.add(buttb);
           panel.add(fieldb);
           panel.add(result);
           panel.add(fieldc);

           butta.addActionListener(new GetA());
           buttb.addActionListener(new GetB());

           frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
           frame.pack();
           frame.setVisible(true);

        }

        class GetA implements ActionListener
        { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t1e)
          { aa = Integer.parseInt(fielda.getText()); }
        }

        class GetB implements ActionListener
        { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent t1e)
          { bb = Integer.parseInt(fieldb.getText()); }
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try
          { new Wscalcclient();
              calc.Calculator_Service service = new calc.Calculator_Service();
            calc.Calculator port = service.getCalculatorPort();


            BufferedReader keybrd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("enter number a: ");
            int a = Integer.parseInt(keybrd.readLine());
            System.out.println("enter number b: ");
            int b= Integer.parseInt(keybrd.readLine());

            int cc = port.add(a,b);
            System.out.println("sum = " + cc);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          { System.out.println("exception = " + ex);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this [tag:homework]?  If not, I'd suggest using a single field and the [ScriptEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).

Comment: Hey can you paste the code where you are reading the input (i.e. the add() function)

Comment: I love questions that assert that some basic function of Java is "not working".

Comment: Instead of posting the whlesale copy of code, just post the segment of code that is the actual cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You are setting `bb` and `aa` in your `ActionListener`s.  You never again examine ("read") those values.  So how do you know they are getting the wrong value?  You don't have any code that actually uses them.

Comment: What code do I need to use so that i get the value of aa to be assigned into a and the value of bb to be assigned into b. I have tried a lot of things but i just dont seem to get it right. Please help THANK YOU